# Output option in pandas module

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

below I have mentioned my python script, my input_file formats and output. I have no idea that how can i get my expected output.

My script:

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.read_csv('PB-Energy-A.txt', sep="\s+", header=None)
print (A.mean())

B = pd.read_csv('PB-Energy-B.txt', sep="\s+", header=None)   
print (B.mean())

Complex = pd.read_csv('PB-Energy-complex.txt', sep="\s+", header=None)
print (Complex.mean())
```

File_Look_like:

PB-Energy-A.txt

```
-1598.86
-1640.70
-1632.16
-1701.46
```

PB-Energy-B.txt

```
-8.82
-8.82
-8.82
-8.82
```

PB-Energy-complex.txt

```
-1598.90
-1640.69
-1632.15
-1701.48
```

Output:

```
0   -1626.801148
dtype: float64
0   -8.82
dtype: float64
0   -1626.807131
dtype: float64
```

Expected Output:

```
A = -1626.801148
B = -8.82
Complex = -1626.807131
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
a = pd.Series([-1626.801148])
print (a)
0   -1626.801148
dtype: float64

print ('A = {}'.format(a[0]))
A = -1626.801148
```

---

```
a = pd.Series([-1626.801148])
b = pd.Series([-8.82])
c = pd.Series([-1626.807131])

out = '''A = {0}
B = {1}
Complex = {2}'''.format(a[0],b[0],c[0])
print (out)
A = -1626.801148
B = -8.82
Complex = -1626.807131
```

Comment: Dear Sir, I did not get, how would I write a = pd.Series([-1626.801148]) in my script because before run the script i will not know this number (-1626.801148)

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Answer (score 1):

To get the output in the format you want. Add a label for your mean values in your print statements, with the label and variable separated by a comma, as follows:

`In: print("A = ", A.mean())`

`Out: A = -1626.801148`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome Alex. I think jezrael's solution is more complete.